# Build error (SourceMapConcat) no such file or directory, open tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-.tmp/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js

Tags: jquery, ember.js

When I am trying to run my ember application I am getting this few depreciations, warnings & this build error.

> Build failed. Build Error (SourceMapConcat)
>
> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/home/metro/dhi_workspace/metropolis_sw/source/ui_ember/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-DY5tdz4b.tmp/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'

[The error which is coming o console on ember serve/build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0DG5.png)

As a solution when I am trying to update jquery : bower install jquery ror delete bower_components & update all bower packages: bower install I am getting options like this. Which one should I choose ? Is there some other way to solve the build error.

[the options i am getting on bower install jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncSZK.png)

[my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFR1k.png)
[My pacakge-lock.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JdKz.png)

Comment: Do you have an `app.import()` in your `ember-cli-build.js`, which pulls in bower? When did you started to see this error? Are you using a strategy to lock dependencies like `yarn.lock` or `npm-package.lock`? Do you see this error only on your computer or also on CI?

Comment: I am getting this error while I am trying to build/run my ember application. I am in the process of upgrading node and ember framework from 1.13 to 2.4. 
Yes my `ember-cli-build.js` has
` app.import('bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js');app.import('bower_components/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js'); .. so on`
The application has both bower_components(bower) and node_modules(node)
for locking npm packages It has package-lock.json I will attach it I above question.
I am seeing this in my local system as till all the errors are resolved & software is running I can push it to main branch

Comment: It seem as if the file `bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js` does not exist. Did you verified that it exists on file system after installing bower dependencies? jQuery may have changed file system layout in the NPM package between the versions.

Comment: I checked, It exists at this location `bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js` but the `bower_components` does not exist at this location `home/metro/dhi_workspace/metropolis_sw/source/ui_ember/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-DY5tdz4b.tmp/bower_components/` which is I suppose automatically created

Comment: Please help me out !

Comment: I would need a reproduction to debug the issue myself. Otherwise it's just guessing. I would recommend that you go back to the working version and try to do identify which exact change breaks it. If I got you right, you are updating node and ember and jQuery and maybe even other dependencies at the same time. I would recommend to do it step by step. This will give you a clear trace what step is breaking.

Comment: Actually after I started the upgrade work I am in pursuit to bring it in working state. to upgrade ember `ember-cli-update` is used which could only be installed if node is upgraded, we previously had 0.12v. So I upgraded node and ember & started getting 864 vulnerabilities of package depreciations which I solved as suggested by `npm audit` by upgrading several node packages. now only few of them are left which require ember3.14 but I want to make the software stable with ember2.4 first. looks we can live with it for the time being then....

Comment: solving ember build/run related errors. I updated few bower packeages which solved few of depreciations, warings, errors then I got stuck into this one. Can you please give me your other contact so that we can have live discussion